# How to increase a value by 50%?

Tags: java, math, percentage

### Question

I have example of `salary = 2000` and I want to **increase the salary by a bonus** of `50%`, resulting in a salary of `3000`.

So like:

```
salary = salary + 50% of the salary
```

---

### Attempt

I tried implementing it like this:

```
int salary = 2000;
salary = salary + 50 % salary;

System.out.println(salary);
```

but I got `2050` as result, not `3000`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `%` does not mean "percent" in Java, or most other programming languages.

Comment: Think about it this way: 50% is "half" and "half" could be expressed as 0.5. So "add 50% of salary means something like `salary = salary + 0.5 * salary`, `salary += 0.5 * salary` or `salary *= 1.5` (you might need to cast to `int` though).

Comment: use `salary = (int) (1.5 * salary);`.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is multiply by 1.5

Comment: `salary = 3 * salary / 2;` or `salary += salary / 2;`, if you want to do it all in integer arithmetic.

Comment: salary *= 1.5 will do the trick.  A general way would be salary *= (1.0 + fraction)

Answer (score 3):

You'd multiply

```
int salary = 2000;  
salary = (int) (1.5 * salary);
```

Note that this is only correct for even integers.

You shouldn't use ints, floats, or doubles for currency types

Comment: I would avoid casting the value to `int`. That would mean that the value would be rounded and that might not be what is intended.

Comment: @JoãoDias how are you going to do it without rounding, given that `salary` is an int?

Comment: If a non-decimal value is mandatory of course we would need to round it, but I don't see anything in the question stating that a non-decimal value is intended.

Comment: Lets ask OP and wait for a clarification. Until then, having both answers seems to be a good compromise, I think. @JoãoDias

Comment: Why not use `int` for currency, other than you'd want it to represent cents rather than dollars (or whatever local currency is), and range could be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```java
int salary = 2000;
double finalSalary = salary + 0.5*salary;
System.out.println(finalSalary);
```

or

```java
int salary = 2000;
double finalSalary = salary * 1.5;
System.out.println(finalSalary);
```

Comment: (or just `* 1.5`)

Comment: Good point! I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`50 % salary`

means "the remainder of dividing 50 by `salary`", because `%` is the [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html). Since `50 < salary`, the value of that expression is just 50.

50% of `salary` is given by `salary / 2`. So you can write:

```
salary = salary + (salary / 2);
// or
salary += salary / 2;
// or
salary = salary * 3 / 2;
// etc.
```